# Exception while using primary key with "underscore" character in apache ignite

Tags: ignite

Following exception occurs when using apache ignite data grid with schema import utility. A table "employee" created with primary key "emp_no" as the column name.
generated pojo classes and configuration using apache ignite schema import utility. tried executing example program that comes with distribution. Following it the exception.
apache ignite version is : 1.5.0-final

```
    [16:45:58,890][ERROR][exchange-worker-#49%null%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Failed to reinitialize local partitions (preloading will be stopped): GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=1], nodeId=1073ac4a, evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to register query type: TypeDescriptor [name=Employees, fields={empNo=class java.lang.Object, birthDate=class java.sql.Date, firstName=class java.lang.Object, lastName=class java.lang.Object, gender=class java.lang.Object, hireDate=class java.sql.Date}, indexes={PRIMARY=IndexDescriptor [type=SORTED]}, fullTextIdx=null, keyCls=class java.lang.Object, valCls=class java.lang.Object, valTextIdx=false, registered=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.registerType(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1167)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.initializeCache(GridQueryProcessor.java:291)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart(GridQueryProcessor.java:457)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:1038)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1648)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCachesStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1563)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.startCaches(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:956)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:523)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:1297)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "EMP_NO" not found; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE "EmployeesCache".Employees (_key OTHER NOT NULL,_val OTHER,empNo OTHER,birthDate DATE,firstName OTHER,lastName OTHER,gender OTHER,hireDate DATE) engine "org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Table$Engine" [42122-175]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:172)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:149)
    at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:626)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing$TableDescriptor.createIndexes(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1984)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Table.<init>(GridH2Table.java:106)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Table$Engine.createTable(GridH2Table.java:675)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Table$Engine.createTable(GridH2Table.java:659)
    at org.h2.schema.Schema.createTable(Schema.java:584)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.CreateTable.update(CreateTable.java:135)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:79)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:253)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:181)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:156)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Table$Engine.createTable(GridH2Table.java:700)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.createTable(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1288)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.registerType(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1160)
    ... 10 more
[16:45:58,890][ERROR][exchange-worker-#49%null%][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Runtime error caught during grid runnable execution: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, gridName=null, finished=false, isCancelled=false, hashCode=2115830072, interrupted=false, runner=exchange-worker-#49%null%]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.onExchangeDone(GridCacheProcessor.java:1723)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onDone(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onDone(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:87)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:334)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:873)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:1297)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems like if the table is having any index that has columns with "_" character is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of bugs fixed in Schema Import Utility recently.
Could you try to re-generate POJOs and configs one more time using Schema Import Utility from latest [nightly build](https://builds.apache.org/view/H-L/view/Ignite/job/Ignite-nightly/lastSuccessfulBuild/)?